# Odd terms of fibonacci ratio sequence are bounded above by $\phi$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I want to show that the odd terms of $r_k=\frac{x_{k+1}}{x_k}$ are bounded above by $\phi$ (Golden ratio); where $x_k$ is the fibonacci sequence.

My work so far:
We use induction to show that $r_k<\phi$ if $k$ is odd.

Let $P(j)$ be the proposition that $r_{2j-1}<\phi$. The case for $P(1)$ is trivial. We show that $P(j)$ implies $P(j+1)$. That is, we show that
$$r_{2j-1}<\phi \implies r_{2j+1}<\phi$$
By the definition of $r_k$, we know that $r_{2j+1}=1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{r_{2j-1}}}$. Now
\begin{align*}
r_{2j-1}<\phi & \implies \frac{1}{r_{2j-1}}>\frac{1}{\phi}\\
& \implies 1+\frac{1}{r_{2j-1}}>\frac{1}{\phi}\\
& \implies \frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{r_{2j-1}}}<\phi\\
& \implies
\end{align*}

Am I going in the wrong direction? If so, can you guide me a bit into the right direction. Otherwise can you hint me what should be my next step be?

Answer (score 2):

You're close, but in the second step, you have

\begin{align*}
 \frac{1}{r_{2j-1}}>\frac{1}{\phi} \implies 1+\frac{1}{r_{2j-1}}>\frac{1}{\phi}
\end{align*}

This is just adding $1$ to the LHS which will not yield a very tight bound since now the LHS will surely be larger than the RHS (and this will become more pronounced at every step in the reccurence).  You should instead make the stronger conclusion that

\begin{align*}
 \frac{1}{r_{2j-1}}>\frac{1}{\phi} \implies 1+\frac{1}{r_{2j-1}}>1+\frac{1}{\phi}
\end{align*}

Can you see how to finish the proof now?

Comment: Gotcha! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** Rewriting your expression for $r_{2 j + 1}$ as a proper fraction yields
$$r_{2 j + 1} = 2 - \frac{1}{r_{2 j - 1} + 1} ,$$
and using the inductive hypothesis gives
$$r_{2 j + 1} < 2 - \frac{1}{\phi + 1} .$$
On the other hand, rearranging the quadratic equation $\phi^2 = \phi - 1$ satisfied by $\phi$ gives $(\phi + 1)(-\phi + 2) = 1$.